# Expression method, default value for the body

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nhibernate, predicate

I have this code :

```
var listExpression = new List<Expression>();
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

var memberExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, MyProperty);
    listExpression.Add(
    Expression.Call(
        ((MemberExpression)memberExpression), "Contains", null,
        Expression.Constant((string)MyValue))
    );

Expression body = Expression.Constant(true);
foreach (var expression in listExpression)
    body = Expression.And(body, expression);

return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
```

The result of this is :

```
"True & $var1.AGE >= 5"
```

I don't have any problem when I use this predicate with Entity Framework but not work with NHiernate. I think the problem is the "True". Is it possible to create this predicate without this "True" ?

Comment: Not exactly a straight answer, but: could you try replacing this code with an equivalent based on [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) to see if that clears the problem? (As a bonus you'll gain a ton of readability.)

Comment: Updated the code, forgot a line.

Comment: @Kris-I: what are you placing `True` in expression for?

Comment: @Dennis why you means ? I'd like don't have this true

Comment: @Kris-I: please, post LINQ sample, which you want to build with expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
Expression body = Expression.Constant(true);
foreach (var expression in listExpression)
    body = Expression.And(body, expression);
```

by

```
var body = listExpression.First();//check first if listExpression.Any() would be better
listExpression.Skip(1).Aggregate(body, Expression.And);
```